# Associate data with widgets (not the other way around) - SQL data

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a G/SQL cloud data I am using with App Maker.

I have a table with lots of relational data, that I needed to use a calculated datasource for (due to SQL query complexity). This is all great.  I've made a table based page with a datasource of this calculated data. 
It shows me all the data I want to see, including related data - not just the main table data.

However, I want to make a row clickable so that users can edit the original data record.

For the life of me, I cannot get the record associated with an edit page.  My edit page is a complete page - not a fragment. I have verified that I can see the key value in my edit page, but cannot get widgets on that page associated with the original table record!

I've even tried many things.  selectKey(), queries for the ID and even to use a server function to query the key to see if that would set the record so I could reference something like: 
`app.datasources.<table>.item.<field>` 
But no go!  All attempts come up with null records or the last record in my query.

**More Info:**
I have the table associated with the edit page as a datasource.  I have tried both references as app.datasources... and widget.datasource... to no avail.
The data I am using is a route table with related tables for customer pickup, dropoff, service type, rates etc.  So the calculated data source is the route record, showing the user customer names etc.  Clicking this record is what I cannot get associated with an edit page with datasource set to the uncalculated route table.

**Another Attempt:**
I set up another datasource under my route table as route_id, with Query Builder selected as defined as:

```
id = :route_id
```

route_id is defined as bound to a property on the route listing page called RouteID.
Here's a graphic to help clarify:
[image]

On the route listing page, when a row is clicked I do the following:

```
var key = widget.children.RouteKey.text;
app.pages.RouteList.properties.RouteID  = parseInt(key);
app.datasources.route_id.load();
app.showPage(app.pages.RouteEdit);
```

*The id value RouteKey is loaded with each row, as a hidden label - the user doesn't need to see it.*

All seems logical and fair to me, but **no record data** shows when the edit page appears?!  Is this an async timing issue?!

Here's what I see when I click a row *[don't confuse the (+) button with an add page.  This IS an edit page. This button simply navigates to an add page]*...
[image]

Comment: Did you mean `app.datasourceS.<table>.item.<field>`?

Comment: Ah, yes - will correct. @Pavel  - just to add I am quite sure it is not a silly thing such as syntax as I've likely retyped all code at least 3 times ;v)
Also, I am not getting errors at all.  Just no associated data.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did get my **"Another Attempt"**, above in my question, working!
I had left the form datasource defined directly with the route table and not inherited from the page datasource which was route_id.

I may have been able to do this with an added datasource to the route table with a complex query done as Query Builder code (below gave me the right results):

```
(Archived    = :nuldte)  and
(Shift_fk    = :shift) and
( (RouteDate = :rtdte) or ( (PUStatus = :done ) and (DOStatus = :nulsts) ) )
```

Graphic:
[image]

*NOTE: "Archived" is used instead of Delete. We never delete records*

However, this is **very slow** to render, especially on mobile devices.
The calculated datasource is MUCH quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this:

```javascript
// onClick row's event handler
var id = widget.datasource.item.id;
var routDs = app.datasources.rout_id;

routDs.query.filters.id._equals = id;
routDs.load();
app.showPage(app.pages.RouteEdit);
```

Note, this code doesn't need page custom properties and datasource parameters, feel free to remove them to play with the snippet.

Comment: Ah, looks much simpler!  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks @Pavel  :v)